# Would background music be a separate background process?

Tags: android, linux, multithreading, process

This is a clarification question on processes vs threads. I know that each app will run as its own separate process, meaning it has its own linux process id and that processes are made up of threads, pieces of code running concurrently. Lets say i start angry birds I know that the app itself has a process id. Would the background music be its own separate process(started by another app that plays music) or would be a separate thread in the original process?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking this and it's impossible to give a definitive answer. Any app developer *may* create a `Service` which runs in a separate process to play background music (if they choose to do it that way). It seems unnecessary though as the standard Android `MediaPlayer` handles its own thread which means it can be used safely within an `Activity` or a `Service` which exists within the app's process.

Comment: its just hard to distinguish all the definitions. Would media player be a separate process(being another application?)

Comment: Please read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html - an app consists of a single process running on one thread. If you create an instance of `MediaPlayer` it will run on that same thread but it also creates its own worker thread to handle the music playback.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is just a media (MediaPlayer) playing in the same app, may be in a separate thread but not necessarily.

Comment: but if it was a media player, wouldnt it have to running its own linux process because its a separate application?

Comment: I do not think that it needs to be a separate linux process in itself because the MediaPlayer class simply provides the implementations required to access media files, decode and play and control them. Don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

background music  uses separate thread. look at the example.

public class Pro extends Activity{

```
MediaPlayer ourSong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pro);
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Pro.this, R.raw.sou);
    // music started
    ourSong.start();
    Thread time = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000);

            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.example.disd.Menu");
                startActivity(openMainActivity);
            }
        }
    };
    time.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
    finish();
}
```

}

please refer the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App

Comment: Wouldnt he media player itself be a separate application?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App